# Creating an initializer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am working with the Stripe API, and I'd like to initialize my key when the application starts up.
In other words, I do not want to set the key in the controller or the stripe object(which I will be creating).

I'm coming from ruby on rails, where I could use a "initializer".  Basically, after all your gems are loaded, rails will look through your initializers and run those.

Is there some sort of equivalent way of doing this in laravel?

Thanks!

Comment: does initializing the api in an initializer file run only once through all the application ? I mean what's the benefit of doing this ? also I can't find bootstrap/start.php in laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it up in `bootstrap/start.php`